# PHP - Where should mysql_close() be put in if-else clause?

Tags: php

I have those lines of code:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    //do some stuff
    mysqli_free_result($rs);
    mysqli_close($con);
    header("location:a.php");
} else {
    mysqli_free_result($rs);
    mysqli_close($con);
    header("location:b.php?message=Failed!");
}
```

### As you see, `mysqli_free_result($rs)` and `mysqli_close($con)` repeat twice. I want to find somewhere to put it just one time and in any case, I want that my connection will close.

The problem fixed!

Comment: You're redirecting either way, so place them before the `if/else`.

Comment: you don't really need that. MySQL will close itself.

Comment: Assign the header string to a variable in the `if/else` blocks, and put `mysql_i*` calls + `header` call outside of the blocks: `if ($x) { $header = 'something'; } else { $x = 'something else';} mysqli_free_results($rs); mysqli_close($con); header($x);`

Comment: If you really want to close it, just place it above your closing PHP tag.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Freeing resources when you're done using them is a good habit, though... especially if you make the move to other languages that require you to manage stuff like that

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem agreed, which is why I added another comment ;-)

Comment: I seem to have fallen onto deaf ears. Moving on.

Comment: header(); does not stop execution, you can call mysql_close() at the bottom and then call exit(); to stop execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this?

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    //do some stuff
    $redirect = 'result_sv.php';
} else {
    $redirect = 'index.php?message=Failed!';
}

mysqli_free_result($rs);
mysqli_close($con);
header("location:".$redirect);
```

Comment: which is what [I suggested here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874951/php-where-should-mysql-close-be-put-in-if-else-clause#comment55513507_33874951) but have yet to get a response.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: sorry, i thought it is quite clear what i have done. there is no voodo magic inside, just a bit of simple logic. i assumed that the OP knows about string concatenation and the relevance of where to output headers from within a php file.